# Is there a way to simplify $2^{2^{n-1}}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

A question from a math noob...

> Is there a way to simplify the following?
> $$2^{2^{n-1}}$$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In general, exponents in a "tower" like that are hard to simplify. Maybe you could try
$$2^{2^{n - 1}} = 2^{2^{n}/2} = \sqrt{2}^{2^{n}}$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please use the [basic tutorial and quick reference guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and also show the work you have done so far.

Comment: Sometimes simpler is in the eye of the beholder, but here I don't see any improvement available.

Answer (score 1):

Not really. $2^{2^{n-1}}$.

If it’s part of an equation you can take the log $2^{n-1} log 2$. Another log and you get $(n-1)log 2 + log log 2$.